# Can't get almost all information from event from service Hook

Tags: visual-studio, service, tfs, hook, trello

I am trying to use the Trello service hook with Team Foundation Server. I have [followed this tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/trello) and the connection worked without problems but, I can't get the informations I need from the Event JSON:
[The Description I Tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIszr.png)

This is the Event JSON:

```
{
    "id": "03c164c2-8912-4d5e-8009-3707d5f83734",
    "eventType": "git.push",
    "publisherId": "tfs",
    "scope": 0,
    "message": {
        "text": "Jamal Hartnett pushed updates to Fabrikam-Fiber-Git:master.",
        "html": "Jamal Hartnett pushed updates to Fabrikam-Fiber-Git:master.",
        "markdown": "Jamal Hartnett pushed updates to `Fabrikam-Fiber-Git`:`master`."
    },
    "detailedMessage": {
        "text": "Jamal Hartnett pushed a commit to Fabrikam-Fiber-Git:master.\n - Fixed bug in web.config file 33b55f7c",
        "html": "Jamal Hartnett pushed a commit to <a href=\"https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/\">Fabrikam-Fiber-Git</a>:<a href=\"https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/#version=GBmaster\">master</a>.\n<ul>\n<li>Fixed bug in web.config file <a href=\"https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/commit/33b55f7cb7e7e245323987634f960cf4a6e6bc74\">33b55f7c</a>\n</ul>",
        "markdown": "Jamal Hartnett pushed a commit to [Fabrikam-Fiber-Git](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/):[master](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/#version=GBmaster).\n* Fixed bug in web.config file [33b55f7c](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/commit/33b55f7cb7e7e245323987634f960cf4a6e6bc74)"
    },
    "resource": {
        "commits": [
            {
                "commitId": "33b55f7cb7e7e245323987634f960cf4a6e6bc74",
                "author": {
                    "name": "Jamal Hartnett",
                    "email": "fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com",
                    "date": "2015-02-25T19:01:00Z"
                },
                "committer": {
                    "name": "Jamal Hartnett",
                    "email": "fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com",
                    "date": "2015-02-25T19:01:00Z"
                },
                "comment": "Fixed bug in web.config file",
                "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/commit/33b55f7cb7e7e245323987634f960cf4a6e6bc74"
            }
        ],
        "refUpdates": [
            {
                "name": "refs/heads/master",
                "oldObjectId": "aad331d8d3b131fa9ae03cf5e53965b51942618a",
                "newObjectId": "33b55f7cb7e7e245323987634f960cf4a6e6bc74"
            }
        ],
        "repository": {
            "id": "278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249",
            "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
            "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249",
            "project": {
                "id": "6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
                "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
                "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
                "state": "wellFormed",
                "visibility": "unchanged"
            },
            "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
            "remoteUrl": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git"
        },
        "pushedBy": {
            "id": "00067FFED5C7AF52@Live.com",
            "displayName": "Jamal Hartnett",
            "uniqueName": "Windows Live ID\\fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com"
        },
        "pushId": 14,
        "date": "2014-05-02T19:17:13.3309587Z",
        "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/pushes/14"
    },
    "resourceVersion": "1.0",
    "resourceContainers": {
        "collection": {
            "id": "c12d0eb8-e382-443b-9f9c-c52cba5014c2"
        },
        "account": {
            "id": "f844ec47-a9db-4511-8281-8b63f4eaf94e"
        },
        "project": {
            "id": "be9b3917-87e6-42a4-a549-2bc06a7a878f"
        }
    },
    "createdDate": "2017-07-21T16:48:44.312Z"
}
```

This is the Request that was send to Trello:

```
Method: POST
URI: https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=7d6630fd03ac2b6fc9fde2f2ef0c4096&token=********
HTTP Version: 1.1
Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}
Content:
{
  "name": "Test Nº  ",
  "desc": "Description: ",
  "pos": "top",
  "due": null,
  "labels": "green",
  "idList": "5935a0d45ff8e5a6c8f828b9"
}
```

The only field that I could get/read from the Event JSON was the "message".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where can I change the TFS address and Commit ID? I could not find where I can change this.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, got the same result as you. Seems we are using the wrong placeholder in this case. According to your send Request , `resource.pushID` & `resource.commits.[0].comment` is not replaced by values from the event that was raised. However, have tried multiple placeholders such as `git.xx` `code.xx`, none of this worked, but it works well with build.id/ workitem.id for other event. I'm afraid it's not able to get other info except message/detailedmessage or the format is hard code in the codepush event.

Comment: Do you know where can I learn how to make sure that the format is hard coded and how I can get the info? I don't get why they make a simple thing so hard...

Comment: Eddie is right you should use `push` as the resource in this case. The docs are not so clear.  In the end, it was something so simple. However the corresponding `checkin` is not work for Code checked in event. The docs could definitely be more clear in how the resource are for each event  which applied to help avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the push ID and comments, the description is:

```
{{push.pushId}}

{{push.commits[0].comment}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

*Eddie* is right you should use `push` as the resource in this case. The docs are not so clear.  In the end, it was something so simple. However the corresponding `checkin` is not work for **Code checked in** event.

The docs could definitely be more clear in how the resource are for each event  which applied to help avoid this confusion.

---

> The basic form of the placeholder is `{{resource.field}}` where
>   **resource is the name of the resource raising the event** (workitem, build, etc) and **field is a field within the resource section of the
>   event**, like id. So, if the subscription were for a completed build,
>   it might be something like:
>
> ```
> Build {{build.id}} completed at {{build.finishTime}}
> ```

Seems the issue is you are using the wrong placeholder in this case. According to your send Request , `resource.pushID` & `resource.commits.[0].comment` is not replaced by values from the event that was raised.

Comment: Thank you for your help.