# Jamal Hartnett pushed updates to Fabrikam-Fiber-Git:master

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I integrated Azure Devops to my Azure Web App (chat bot). It was working yesterday when I made commits, but now I checked the history logs and found the following:

`Jamal Hartnett pushed updates to Fabrikam-Fiber-Git:master.`

Who the heck is Jamal Hartnet and what is Fabrikam-Fiber-Git? Anyways, Here's the full error log:

> Failed
>   Sent at: Wednesday, February 6, 2019 12:02:59 AM
>   Message
>   Jamal Hartnett pushed updates to Fabrikam-Fiber-Git:master.
>
> Error Message
>   Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Sdk.Server.Consumers.ServiceHooksConsumerResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Consumers" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
>
> Error Details
>   System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Sdk.Server.Consumers.ServiceHooksConsumerResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Consumers" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
>    at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
>    at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
>    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Consumers.ServiceHooksConsumerService.AttachSessionTokenToEventIfNeeded(IVssRequestContext requestContext, Notification notification, ConsumerActionImplementation actionImpl) in d:\v2.0\P1_work\9\s\ServiceHooks\Sdk\Consumers\ServiceHooksConsumerService.cs:line 623
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Consumers.ServiceHooksConsumerService.GetConsumerActionTaskForNotification(IVssRequestContext requestContext, Notification notification) in d:\v2.0\P1_work\9\s\ServiceHooks\Sdk\Consumers\ServiceHooksConsumerService.cs:line 320
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Server.ServiceHooksService.d__68.MoveNext() in d:\v2.0\P1_work\9\s\ServiceHooks\Service\Server\ServiceHooksService.cs:line 2785

Comment: You should post your question as an issue on the github repo itself, not here. This isn't the place to ask about various commits etc for a given repo, or who a contributor is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an issue specific to a github repo and a recent commit, and should be posted as an issue to the repo.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for the feedback. I'm actually the owner and only contributor of the repository. It's also hosted on Azure Dev Ops. Not Github. I don't have a reason to think this is specific to my repository only.

Comment: Other people are also seeing this mysterious "Jamal Hartnet" guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243202/cant-get-almost-all-information-from-event-from-service-hook

Comment: @DavidMakogon FYI this isn't about a specific repository. As far as I noticed, everytime a service hook is created between TFS or Azure and Slack a message like this or this exact message is generated and posted. Author is always 'Jamal Hartnet'.

Comment: For whatever reason, I'm not having this issue anymore.

Comment: Mr. Mastodon :) -- Here's my comment, sufficient reputation or not. Please be aware enough when you read over a submission. Try to realize WHY it was submitted and others have something to say about it. This too was confusing for me. This is errant test text, clearly. There should be an explanation for it to prevent this sort of confusion. I doubted my little test subscription got hacked but nonetheless was concerned. Why are you so arrogant as to tell someone to get sufficient reputation. Answer people's questions, help them, or get out of the way please.

Answer (score 8):

Most probably you have pressed to test button, it is just a test message to check integration.

Comment: This should have been a comment, please leave comments such as this one once you have enough reputation. Until then, try to write some quality answers.

Comment: Here's my comment, sufficient reputation or not.  Please be aware enough when you read over a submission.  Try to realize WHY it was submitted and others have something to say about it.

This too was confusing for me.  This is errant test text, clearly.  There should be an explanation for it to prevent this sort of confusion.

I doubted my little test subscription got hacked but nonetheless was concerned.

Why are you so arrogant as to tell someone to get sufficient reputation.  Answer people's questions, help them, or get out of the way please.

Answer (score 2):

Googling shows me this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops

My guess is that somebody took a git tutorial too literally.

Answer (score 2):

When subscribing to a Webhook in Azure DevOps, it gives you the option to "test" to make sure you have subscribed to the Appropriate webhook's URL.  You can set up many different triggers, including Push, Build and PR triggers.

More than likely, you subscribed to a webhook and hit the "test" button.  It can be safely ignored.

To answer your question, Jamal Harnett is a dummy user used by Azure DevOps for the purpose of testing webhooks. Fabrikam-Fiber-Git is just his fabricated git repo.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to add Service Hooks for Jenkins while [following this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/jenkins?view=azure-devops) and testing the connection, it returns me this sample text. [image]